# Map in react js

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to map but I don't manage to map orders here. It's written cannot read property of undefined but products work.

This is my class:

```
const p = products.map(p => {
  return (
    <Product
    key={p._id}
    product={p}
    />
  );
});
const o = orders.map(o => {
  return (
    <div
    key={o._id}
    product={p}
    />
  );
});
```

This is the console log of the object:

[image: console log of the fetched data that I want to map]

Comment: Can you please share console.log of orders.

Comment: Where does orders come from? The second item in the array you posted?

Comment: What is the exact error you are getting?

Comment: There is an array inside an array. You expect there to be a single object in each item  in your array.

Answer (score 2):

In second map you should change product={p} to product={o}. P is unknown variable there.

```
const o = orders.map(o => {
  return (
    <div
    key={o._id}
    product={o}
    />
  );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

As @IfSoGirl mentioned you need to supply o but not p to product prop in second map method

Further to that, here is your simplified map functions. Since it’s single jsx element under map so no need of return syntax

```
   const p = products.map(p => <Product key={p._id} product={p}/>);

   const o = orders.map(o => <div key={o._id} product={o}/>);
```